# uncaught typeError: cannot call method 'extend' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

Getting this error when trying to load a rails 3 app with backbone.

On my rails console i keep getting the following.

> 304 not modified.
>
> could not determine content-length of response body.
>
> set content-length of the response or set response#chunked = true

Comment: did you include underscore.js?

Comment: yeah //= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require backbone
//= require jquery-1.5.1.min
//= require underscore
//= require mynotes

Comment: do i need to combine the underscore.js file into the backbone as one file or something?

Comment: If you have the require_tree directive, you shouldn't need to require the libs manually.

Comment: require tree list things alphabetically, so should i remove this? so i can add them in the correct order, does underscore need to be before or after backbone?

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem, make sure your javascript files are being called in the correct order. jQuery should be first, then underscore, and finally Backbone.

For example if you weren't using require.js:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="underscore.js"></script>
<script src="backbone.js"></script>
```